# Whether document in a dropbox can be changed by multiple users at same time?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to change a document simultaneously by multiple users while being actively shared in Dropbox (much similar to what Google docs has to offer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two users try and edit a document at the same time then a conflicted copy of the document is saved in the same directory.  Is this what you are asking, or are you trying to find out it there's a plugin available to do this (to my knowledge there isn't)?

This is the link to the dropbox [help article](https://www.dropbox.com/help/36/en).

Comment: yes you are right. is it possible to have no conflicted copy even if the document get accessed by multiple users? Thanks in advance